# when to the 'the' in a sentence!

Tags: grammaticality, articles, conjunction-reduction

after 'share knowledge of the' why does 'context' not have an article after it?
As opposed to

The first group consists of nouns which refer to shared knowledge of the situation or the context.

why use the structure below?

> The first group consists of nouns which refer to shared knowledge of
>   the situation or context.

Comment: Why would you ever put an article *after* the word "context" above, given that that is the last word of the sentence??

Comment: I have no idea, you tell me lol

Comment: By 'after' do you mean 'before'?

Comment: This is mere conjunction reduction. We get asked this 100 times a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do present your question in a more understandable and grammatically correct fashion.

Back to the problem, the word “the” here is optional.  For instance, you can say “the dog and the cat” or “the dog and cat”, both are grammatically correct.